# pseudo selector for second child exact like first-child

Tags: css

Is there a identical psuedo selector that acts like `:first-child` but with second child of a parent element?

I used
`:nth-child(2)` but is that the only equivalent it seems it resolves slightly differently when styles are applied. I also like the legibility of `:first-child`

If that is the equivalent why use `:first-child` and not `:nth-child(1)` what is correct selectors with most support for accessing first and second child elements of div container?

Comment: You mean `:nth-child` not `.nth-child`

Comment: Yes! Thanks good catch, I meant this!

Comment: What do you mean by “resolves slightly differently”? A functional difference, or a difference in how it looks like in CSS code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such selector. You should use `:nth-child(2)`.

And `:first-child` is older browser compatible than `:nth-child(1)` so we use `:first-child`

And if you're using `:nth-child(2)`, you shouldn't be confusing to use `:nth-child(1)` in your own.

Comment: Yes... The concern comes almost only with IE(as usual...). `:first-child` works with IE7+, while `:nth-child` is IE9+

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `:nth-child(2)`, you can use the combined selector

```
:first-child + *
```

which refers to the same elements, since it denotes any element that is the next sibling for any first child. More normally, you would be using something like `p:nth-child(2)`, and then the equivalent selector is

```
:first-child + p
```

“Equivalence” means here that the selectors denotes the same sets of elements. They are different in specificity, so care needs to be taken when this matters.

The combined selector is slightly more cross-browser, since the constructs involved are supported by IE 8, which does not support `:nth-child(2)`.

Example:

```html
<style>
:first-child + p {
  outline: solid red;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
  background: gray;
}
</style>
<div>
<p>foo
<p>bar
<p>more
</div>
```

Comment: For IE 7 (and IE 6!), you need either a polyfill like http://selectivizr.com or the clumsy way of manually adding `class` attributes where needed.